# Integration of 0-th order Bessel function using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integral, bessel-functions

I have simple question. I'm trying to evaluate improper integral of 0th order Bessel function using Matlab R2012a:

```
v = integral(@(x)(besselj(0, x), 0, Inf)
```

which gives me v = 3.7573e+09. However this should be v = 1 in theory. When I'm trying to do

```
v = integral(@(l)besselj(0,l), 0, 1000)
```

it results to v = 1.0047. Could you briefly explain me, what is going wrong with integration? And how to properly integrate Bessel-type functions?

Answer (score 1):

At first I was sceptical that taking an integral over a Bessel function would produce finite results. Mathematica/Wofram Alpha however showed that the result is finite, but it is [not for the faint of heart](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+zeroth+bessel+function+from+0+to+infinity).

However, then I was pointed to [this site](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=570379) where it is explained how to do it properly, and that the value of the integral should be 1.

I experimented a bit to verify the correctness of their statements:

```
    F = @(z) arrayfun(@(y) quadgk(@(x)besselj(0,x), 0, y), z);

    z = 10:100:1e4;

    plot(z, F(z))
```

which gave:

[image: bessel integral]

so clearly, the integral indeed seems to converges to 1. Shame on Wolfram Alpha!

(Note that this is kind of a misleading plot; try to do it with `z = 10:1e4;` and you'll see why. But oh well, the principle is the same anyway).

This figure also shows precicely what the problem is you're experiencing in Matlab; the value of the integral is like a damped oscillation around 1 for increasing `x`. Problem is, the dampening is very weak -- as you can see, my `z` needed to go all the way to `10,000` just to produce this plot, whereas the oscillation amplitude was only decreased by ~0.5.

When you try to do the improper integral by messing around with the 'MaxIntervalCount' setting, you get this:

```
    >> quadgk(@(x)besselj(0,x), 0, inf, 'maxintervalcount', 1e4) 

    Warning: Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals in use.
    Approximate bound on error is 1.2e+009. The integral may not exist, or
    it may be difficult to approximate numerically.
    Increase MaxIntervalCount to 10396 to enable QUADGK to continue for 
    another iteration. 
    > In quadgk>vadapt at 317
      In quadgk at 216
```

It doesn't matter how high you set the `MaxIntervalCount`; you'll keep running into this error. Similar things also happen when using `quad`, `quadl`, or similar (these underly the R2012 `integral` function).

As this warning and plot show, the integral is just not suited to approximate accurately by any quadrature method implemented in standard MATLAB (at least, that I know of).

I believe the proper analytical derivation, as done on the physics forum, is really the only way to get to the result without having to resort to specialized quadrature methods.

Comment: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=570379 looks like it should be 1 :/ see post #9

Comment: @Dan: [Check mathematicas answer](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=BesselJ%5B0%2C+x%5D&random=false); that sure don't look like '1' to me :) (or well, a '2' than, since it's improper, but...same thing)

Comment: Hmmm, didn't load nicely on my side. This has integral of 1: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+first+bessel+function+from+0+to+infinity but it looks like a reflection of yours. So maybe OP is integrating the wrong bessel function? but it doesn't look like it based on the result where `inf` is replaced with `1000`. I wonder if it starts to converge if that `1000` is replaced with `1000000`. Don't have access to matlab now to check though.

Comment: @Dan: Well, see my edit; I was indeed wrong. Interesting problem! I'll experiment a bit more.

Comment: @Dan: Anyway, the question was about *zeroth* order bessel funtion, so, [use the corresponding mathematica solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+zeroth+bessel+function+from+0+to+infinity).

Comment: Thank's! I've realized that it would be better to switch to some analytical expression that could be approximated more efficiently

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) to do an improper integral on an oscillatory function:

```
q = integral(fun,0,Inf,'RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',1e-13)
```

in the docs the example is

```
fun = @(x)x.^5.*exp(-x).*sin(x);
```

but I guess in your case try:

```
q = integral(@(x)(besselj(0, x),0,Inf,'RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',1e-13)
```